# nodejs promise wrong usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Environment: node v5.1.0 on Windows7.

I'm trying to send data to `publish_url` using post. 
I would like to run another function in the catch of the `init` or the `then`.
But don't reach those parts.

The prints "call to success handle func" and "call to failed handle func" isn't being called.

Please advise me in what I'm doing wrong?

```
var request = require('request');
var publish_url = "https://some_server.com";
function publish_data(url, data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){  
        request.post(
            url,
            { json:
                {"handshake":{"data":data}}
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log(body);
                    resolve(body);
                } else {
                    console.log("Error:",body);
                    reject(body);
                }
            }
        );
    });
}

function init(){
     console.log("init 1");
     try{
        publish_data(publish_url, 5).then(
            function(obj){
                console.log("call to success handle func");
            });

     }catch(e){
        console.log("call to failed handle func");      
     }

     console.log("init 3");
}

console.log("start");
init();
console.log("end");
```

Comment: Hey, "bare" WHAT with you? Maybe you meant "bear with me"???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `try-catch`

Promises works that way:

```
publish_data(publish_url, 5).then(function(obj){
 console.log("call to success handle func");
}).catch(function(data){
 console.error(data);
});
```

Here's a simple example of JS promise:

```js
function firstFunct(){
 return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  data = 5;
  if(data == 5) resolve(data);
  else reject(data);
 })
}

firstFunct().then(function(data){
  console.log("Resolved, data expected to be 5:" + data); // if Promise is resolved
}).catch(function(data){
  console.error("Rejected, data is not 5:" + data) // if Promise is rejected
});
```